# Applpescript: Reading Text file for List of Files

Tags: automation, applescript, text-files

I have been trying to cobble together a script to take a list of files from a text document and have applescript go through the list line by line and then do something with the file. In this case it is changing the label on the file, but we would use it in other instances to move files, etc.

It works with a test file on my desktop the files get marked with the purple Label, but when trying to run it in the folder I actually need to it fails with this error message:

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t set 1 to 5." number -10006 from 1

The text files are the same except for the length of their content.

Could this be a an issues with filenames, and if so how do I make the script more tolerant.

Here is the script:

```
    set textFileContents to POSIX path of (choose file)
set dataList to paragraphs of (read textFileContents as «class utf8»)
tell application "System Events"

    repeat with thisFileName in dataList


        tell application "Finder" to set (label index of files whose name is thisFileName) to 5
    end repeat

end tell
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
1080074 3.tif
1080074 2.tif
1080069_A1.tif
```

---

**Here is the final code from the solution to this problem and some further work I did.**

Thanks to @Mark Setchell & @jackjr300 for all of their patient help.

---

`set justpath to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt "Select the Folder with Files You Want to Use")
set textFileContents to (choose file with prompt "Select the list of files")
set dataList to paragraphs of (read textFileContents as «class utf8»)
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with FileName in dataList
        try -- need a try block to ignore error, in case that the file has been moved or deleted
            set label index of (justpath & FileName as POSIX file as alias) to 5
        end try
    end repeat
end tell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the folder because the finder has no current folder, except the **Desktop** if you don't specify a folder.

```
set textFileContents to choose file
set dataList to paragraphs of (read textFileContents as «class utf8»)
set theFolder to "/Users/jack/Desktop/xxx/yyy" as POSIX file as alias -- change it to the path of your folder
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with thisFileName in dataList
        try -- need a try block to ignore error, in case that the file has been moved or deleted
            set label index of file thisFileName of theFolder to 5
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

Change the path in the third line of this script

--

If the text file contains the full path of the file, you can use this script.

```
set textFileContents to choose file
set dataList to paragraphs of (read textFileContents as «class utf8»)
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with thisPath in dataList
        try -- need a try block to ignore error, in case that the file has been moved or deleted
            set label index of (thisPath as POSIX file as alias) to 5
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Follow Up:
Is there a way to get the full path to the directory from the text file we choose, not the filename path but just the directory it is in? For example we'll call the string justPath.
Then your script could be modified to:

`set label index of (justpath&thispath as POSIX file as alias) to 5`

Comment: or would it be
`set label index of (thispath of (justpath) as POSIX file as alias) to 5
similar to this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4574615?tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a spurious `tell application "System Events"` in there. It works like this:

```
set FileName to POSIX path of (choose file)
set FileRecords to paragraphs of (read FileName)
repeat with ThisFileName in FileRecords
   say ThisFileName
   tell application "Finder" to set (label index of files whose name is thisFileName) to 5
end repeat
```

Note that my test file isn't UTF8.

**Update**

By the way, if all you want do is set the label colour on some files, it may be easier to do that from the Terminal and not worry with Applescript. Say you start the Terminal, and go to your Desktop like this

```
cd Desktop
```

you can then change the labels of all files on your Desktop (and in any subdirectories) whose names contain "Freddy" followed by "Frog" (i.e "fileForFreddyFrog.txt", "file from Freddy the Frog.php")

```
find . -name "*Freddy*Frog*" -exec xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "0000000000000000000700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I am still getting the same error but now my computer is actually saying with the text to speech voice the name of the first file in the text document and then I get the same error code.

Here is the list of files in my text file that is failing. Could it be in the file name.

1030172.tif
1080074 3.tif
1080074 2.tif
1080069_A1.tif

Comment: So if you comment out the line `tell application finder` by adding two minus signs at the start like this `-- tell applcation finder...`, does it say the names of all the files in the text document properly? Also, add a `beep` immediately above the line `end repeat`.

Comment: Please click `edit` underneath your question and paste the contents of the file in there - preceding each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: Also just in case it is relevant I generated the file by searching for certain patterns in the file names in a large folder. 9000+files. I then copied the files and pasted them into a plain text document. That generated the file name with the full path. I then did a find/change to remove the path.

Comment: Mark,

If I comment out the line as you requested it reads the file fine. And beeps.

Comment: I am guessing your script isn't running in the directory where the files are... try adding the full path at the front of the filenames, e.g. `"/Users/Izzy/Desktop/Some file.jpg"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I am cleaning up 9000+ files in an image library that is in use daily and for which 750 new images are added every 6 months. The text file I built was searching for files that are not named with our standard naming conventions. The idea is to be able to quickly build a text file I can either pass down to my junior staff or run myself that flag these files with an appropriate color so that they can be fixed when time allows. Ultimately I would like to be able to do this with a file spit out from our database of discontinued items.

Comment: Adding the full path, running the script from the same folder as the images and even doing both doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I'm not at my Mac but I think I know the problem - you probably need the mad Apple-style paths with colons rather than (Posix-style) slashes as separators...

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I moved the file back to my desktop and it worked even without the path in the text file. (I have a folder where I run and test scripts on my Desktop to keep things tidy.) There is a space in the name of the folder I was working in so it seems the issue the script is encountering is unsupported characters in the path.  

Anyway to get that input supported or change how it spits out of the path?

Comment: This is become a different question & I am going to post that as a separate thread. Thanks for your help Mark. New to this board what is the ettiquite on giving you credit for all of your help?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't quite hit the mark with my answer. Don't worry about points or anything - the main thing is that you get the problem solved and someone helps you out properly. Good luck and I hope it all works out for you.